# Shadowed property is not set by the designer

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2012, windows-forms-designer

I have a custom control that is derived from `Panel`.

I am shadowing the Size property because I need to adjust it (the control is basically an expander in Winforms):

```vb
Private DesiredSize As Size
Public Shadows Property Size As Size
   Get
       Return DesiredSize
   End Get
   Set(value As Size)
       DesiredSize = value
       AdjustHeight()
   End Set
End Property
```

`AdjustHeight()` more or less sets the base Size to a value based on the IsExpanded Property

```vb
    Public Property CollapsedWidth As Integer
    Private Sub AdjustHeight()
        If IsExpanded Then
            MyBase.Size = DesiredSize
        Else
            Dim newh As Integer = 15
            Dim neww As Integer
            If CollapsedWidth > 0 Then
                neww = CollapsedWidth
            Else
                neww = DesiredSize.Width
            End If
            MyBase.Size = New Size(neww, newh)
        End If
    End Sub
```

I initialize the DesiredSize with `DesiredSize = MyBase.Size` in the constructor.

This works well enough, however I have a problem in the Visual Studio Designer. Whenever I resize the control, the Size property is not updated. The control on the form at Design time resizes, but once I start the application it's back to the initial size, both at runtime as well as at design time.

How is the Size property actually handled in the Designer? Do I maybe need to add some kind of attribute to the shadows Size Property to make it work?

Answers in both VB.NET and C# are very much appreciated.

**Edit:**
I tried adding the  `<DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)>` Tag to the property, because I read that it may help in cases like these, but it doesn't change anything about the behaviour I am experiencing.

**Edit 2:**
I fixed the problem by taking a different path and avoiding shadowing the Size property. However I'll leave the question open, because I still want to know if it would be possible with the approach posted above.

Comment: It might be easier to just handle the SizeChanged event instead of shadowing the property.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't expect a `Shadow`ed property to be readable by the form designer, as it will be treating everything as if it where a `Control` - it has no knowledge of your class, and this is the risk with Shadowing methods - you're providing a new implementation, but only to people that know about you - people that know about your base class, will get your base class' implementation.

Had the [`Control.Size` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.size%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) been overrideable (virtual, if you prefer), then you *could* have overridden it, and it would've worked.

Comment: That is what I don't really understand. If I shadow the Size property, wouldn't the designer think it's the same size property as before? My code would work I this was the case, because it just rerouted the actual setting of the MyBase.Size property through another function.

Comment: Depends if it's using a pointer of the type of the base (say, `Control`), or if it uses reflection for every control. I'd assume it would use the `Control` base class for *most* things, and reflect for any properties *it hasn't already seen*